# How to exclude Header attribute inside unity custom editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm trying to make a custom UnityEditor and stumbled upon a problem for hours. I have this problem when I try to use `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField` on the editor script. I can't use other editor field either because some of my custom class has custom `PropertyDrawer`.

Editor tool I tried to make:

[image]

Here's the code I used in the editor

```
SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(entry.target);

so.Update();
SerializedProperty prop = so.FindProperty(entry.memberName);

if (prop != null)
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(prop, GUIContent.none);

so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

And here is the implementations. I use a custom property drawer for the `Optional<>` :

```
[Header("Targets")]
public Transform targetContainer;

[Header("Position")]
public Optional<AttachMode> attachPosition = new Optional<AttachMode>(AttachMode.Relative, true);
```

Is there any way not to include the [Header] attribute inside the EditorGUILayout.PropertyField?

Comment: Someone managed to do this [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1394991/how-to-preserve-drawing-decoratordrawer-like-heade.html) .. a little dirty though .. but on the other hand, when was editor scripting ever not? ;) Though, is the a reason why to put the headers there in the first place when you want them anyway?

Comment: yes I tried that solution before, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem as it's ignoring my custom propertydrawer. I use header attribute for more organized default inspector, but the problem arise when I tried to get that property for my custom editor window.